# I'm not sure how to get \onlysideX or \Xonlyside to work in reledmac/reledpar?

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I might be missing something obvious but I can't figure out how to get footnotes to appear on only the left or only the right in a pair environment.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\Xonlyside[A]{R}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}

\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
        Column \edtext{1.}{\Afootnote{Footnote.}}
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
        Column 2.
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, if you have a reledmac/reledpar up to date, you get this error message "Afootnote called on left side, despite y
our configuring it to be for the right side only".

The `\Xonlyside[A]{R}` setting just tell to reledpar: if a `\Afootnote` is too long to get to a single right page (in parallel pages, not in parallel column), the end of the footnote won't be printed to the next left page, but only to the next right page.

So, I think you misunderstood this feature, but I don't know what you need exactly. Here, you are in parallel columns and not in parallel pages. If you want to have footnote only on the right side of the page, under the right columns, it is not possible yet, and I don't think it will be possible before many time, as I  have a lot of new feature of reledmac to add before looking for this problem.