# Justify reledpar columns

Tags: reledpar

How do I make both columns justified using reledpar? It looks like my right column (which is RTL) is justified but my left column (LTR) is not. I'm not sure what's causing this.

Here's a MWE without trying any alignment commands. (When I tried this, the opposite happened--only the English side was justified, the Hebrew was flush right.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
        Column 1. The text of this column carries over into a second line.
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
        עמוד \edtext{ב׳.}{\Afootnote{Footnote.}} הטקסט של העמוד הזה נמשך לשורה שנייה.
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As you may notice by the three questions you've asked so far, you are more likely to get an answer if you include a MWE, as you did in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370103/im-not-sure-how-to-get-onlysidex-or-xonlyside-to-work-in-reledmac-reledpar). Good luck!

Comment: I think I just solved my own problem. I found, tucked in a comment on another post, that using the \tolerance command fixes it. I tried that and it worked!