# How to force two-column footnotes to be justified in reledpar?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, reledpar

On reledpar’s manual – on `\raggedX` – it’s said that two-column footnotes are justified by default, but that’s not what I get. From another answer ([Justify reledpar columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370277)) I gather it might be solved using `\tolerance`, but I haven’t found anything more illuminating about that. A minimal working example follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\let\footnote\footnoteA
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\hsizetwocolX[A]{0.48\hsize}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[3]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]} \lipsum[2]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: sample from the output of the code provided]

Comment: On reledmac handbook, it is sais \Xragged concerns paragraphed footnote, not two columns footnotes. You find the way, so nice.

Comment: ah, thank you for your comment and all your hard work, Maïeul! I was too sleep-deprived to find anything :-$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I’ve just found it, by accident, on [Footnote referencing footnote in different stream using reledmac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421926)!

```
\colalignX{\justifying}
```